# Split Comma Separated Value column into two new columns

Tags: mysql

I want to split a column of the MySQL database into two distinct columns.
[image: Snapshot of MYSQL DB table named "mytable"]

Here I want to split each value in the "long" column after the `,` and update the "lat" column with the relevant half of the split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring_index` function as

```
mysql> select substring_index('N27.1963456,E85.234567',',',-1);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('N27.1963456,E85.234567',',',-1) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| E85.234567                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

So the update command will be as

```
update your_table set `lat` = substring_index(`long`,',',-1);
```

**UPDATE**
How to remove the first character

```
mysql> select RIGHT('foobarbar', length('foobarbar')-1);
+-------------------------------------------+
| RIGHT('foobarbar', length('foobarbar')-1) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| oobarbar                                  |
+-------------------------------------------+

mysql> select RIGHT('E85.234567', length('E85.234567')-1);
+---------------------------------------------+
| RIGHT('E85.234567', length('E85.234567')-1) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 85.234567                                   |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

So you can do as

```
update your_table set `lat` = RIGHT(`lat`,length(`lat`)-1);
```

Comment: thanks for response but it says 0 rows effected and no table data was updated

Comment: what is the data type of `lat` ? if its `int` then it needs to be changed to `varchar`

Comment: :P its was in int thats my mistake.
thankyou so much the help bro

Comment: can u please tell me how can i now remove the first character of each value in the long and lat feild

Comment: You mean removing `E85` and `N27` ?

Comment: Watch out, this example calculated the substring index on only one row.  As long as your whole table has the split at the same character, you're ok, but if you had a value like `N27.1234,E85.234567`, then you're hosed.  My solution doesn't have this problem.

Comment: i want to remove the first letter like beloW
E85.2463446 to 85.2463446

Answer (score 1):

This might work to update both columns:

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET `lat`  = TRIM(SUBSTR(`long`,1,INSTR(`long`,',')-1))
    , `long` = TRIM(SUBSTR(`long`,INSTR(`long`,',')+1));
```

Sample output:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| long        | lat          |
+-------------+--------------+
| E85.2463446 | N27.19638836 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Working SQLFiddle example in MySQL 5.5: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a5d7/1/0

**EDIT:** To remove the first character.  And actually handle N/S as +/- and E/W as +/-:

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET `lat`  = REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                  TRIM(SUBSTR(`long`,1,INSTR(`long`,',')-1))
               ,'N','')
               ,'S','-')
    , `long` = REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 TRIM(SUBSTR(`long`,INSTR(`long`,',')+1))
               ,'E','')
               ,'W','-');
```

Input:

```
insert into mytable (`long`) VALUES ('N27.1963, E85.2463446');
insert into mytable (`long`) VALUES ('S37.196336, E104.2463446');
insert into mytable (`long`) VALUES ('N47.19638836, W6.2463446');
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| long        | lat         |
+-------------+-------------+
| 85.2463446  | 27.1963     |
| 104.2463446 | -37.196336  |
| -6.2463446  | 47.19638836 |
+-------------+-------------+
```